# Getting error: Py4JJavaError while writing data from Databricks to sql data-warehouse

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I followed this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/synapse-analytics) writing data from Databricks to sql data-warehouse .

```
datafram.write
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw")
  .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver.......)
  .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true")
  .option("dbTable", "table")
  .option("tempDir", "Blob_url")
  .save()
```

but still I am getting this error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling 0174.save.
: java. lang. ClassNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please follow below steps:**

Configure Azure Storage account access key  with Databricks

```
spark.conf.set(
  "fs.azure.account.key.<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net","Azure_access_key")
```

**Syntax of JDBC URL**

```
jdbc_url = "jdbc:sqlserver://<Server_name>.sql.azuresynapse.net:1433;database<Database_name>;user=<user_name>;password=Vam@9182;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;"
```

[image]

**Sample Data frame:**

[image]

**Writing data from Azure Databricks to Synapse:**

```
df.write \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
  .option("url", jdbc_url) \
  .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true") \
  .option("dbTable", "<table_name>") \
  .option("tempDir", "wasbs://sdd@vambl.blob.core.windows.net/") \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .save()
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]